# How to get index value of ListViewItem in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am making a CRUD Address Book to familiarize myself with WPF Application.

I have three classes: AllContacts, User, and SingleContact. AllContacts uses an ObservableCollection that holds all existing contacts as User Objects. SingleContact is just used simply for displaying the information in a new window (I'm actually not quite sure if this is necessary, what are your thoughts on this)?

I'll explain more below:

I use the ListView to display all the contacts in Window_1 (XAML: AllContacts), as shown:

```
<ListView Name="lbUsers" DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListView}" 
          AlternationCount="2" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" 
          BorderThickness="0" Margin="0,4">                
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Name}" 
                            Width="150"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Phone Number" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding PhoneNumber}" 
                            Width="150"></GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Favorite" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FavoriteStr}" 
                            Width="95"></GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I, then, want to implement a feature such that when I double click on a contact, it will open up Window_2 (class: SingleContact) to display all of the selected contact's information.

The method below is defined in AllContacts:

```
private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    SingleContact contactIndex = new SingleContact( [I WANT TO PASS IN USER OBJECT HERE ] );
    contactIndex.Owner = this;

    if (contactIndex.ShowDialog() != true)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure how to attain the value of the contact being clicked in Window_1 (XAML: AllContacts) and passing the User Object value into Window_2 (class: SingleContact) when I create the new SingleContact object in the code above.

How do I achieve this elegantly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to change the constructor or the window that will display the contact so it can have what to display, or you can add another.

Then when initializing the window, you need to pass the selected item of the listView like this :

```
private void ListViewItem_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     SingleContact contactIndex = new SingleContact((User)this.lbUsers.SelectedItem);
     //if SingleContact is the window
     contactIndex.Show();
}
```

explanation :

```
(User)this.lbUsers.SelectedItem;
```

user is to cast the selected item to your class object, now in the window2, you can display the selected item as you wantn this is for the current window, lbUsers.SelectedItem is the code to access the selected item of your listview.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this definitely worked! How would I display the information on the SingleContact window after? I don't have lbUsers anymore in that window.

Comment: @susieloo_ sorry dinner :D, you need to create a control that can display your object, like another listview or datagrid...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a similar application I've wrote in the past. Basically, you're invoking a command (I'm using MVVM-Light), and passing the selected exercise as a parameter.

```
<ListBox x:Name="LastExercises_ListView"  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredCollection}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedExercise, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                  ToolTip="Double click to edit"
                  >
            <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header ="Edit Exercise"   
                              Command="{Binding EditExercise_Command}" 
                              CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedExercise}"
                    />
                    <MenuItem Header ="Delete Exercise" 
                              Command="{Binding DeleteExercise_Command}" 
                               CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedExercise}"
                    />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ListBox.ContextMenu>
```

If you're not using a framework, you might need to implement something like the `Command`.
Here's where it is defined for me:

```
 xmlns:Command="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
```